# Elastic Beanstalk deploy configuration shows: DBInstance doesn't exist

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk currently working, with her database. The deploy works with any problem. But, my links don't work, so I updated the httpd.conf adding this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And with this it works.
The problem is that due to auto-scaling, every day httpd.conf is restored, so I lose my config, and need to do it again.

I created a config file inside .ebextensions folder:

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
```

But when i try to deploy, my console shows this:

```
2019-04-17 11:27:59    ERROR   Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-vhgv2femtx-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
2019-04-17 11:27:59    ERROR   Updating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-vhgv2femtx-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14XUH5Q77OR6A failed Reason: Template error: DBInstance aa2jl0t4ovd7y8 doesn't exist
2019-04-17 11:27:59    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

But of course it exists.

Someone can help me? I'm totally stucked on this

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `commands` instead of `container_commands`?

Comment: It looks like you have manually deleted (ie in RDS or via CLI/SDK) your database instance, did you?

Comment: @danimal - Yes I tried, but appears the same error. And I don't deleted my RDS instance. Is the same as the first time. The error only appears when I add the container commands

Comment: I deleted all, re-started RDS, reconfigured all, and now it works. Maybe some problems in configuration server before restarting?